# Generics in XAML views: What about the .xaml file (content of the generic class)?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, generics

I have been trying to implement a **generic view in XAML**, this kind of thing in the MyView.**xaml.cs** file:

```
public partial class MyView<T>: UserControl {
  // content...
}
```

And I know that I have to use `x:TypeArguments` for then using MyView. That's right, there's documentation online about that.

But... What about putting something in the MyView**.xaml** file ?

Currently I have a standard:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Some.Name.Space.Views.MyView" 
 *bunch of namespaces declarations*
>
  some content (a StackPanel, a grid, whatever...)
</UserControl>
```

But, of course, the content of the `.xaml` file is going to make a class `MyView` and not `MyView<T>`. And I just cannot find on the internet which specific keyword we have to use in the xaml to say we are declaring the **content** of a **Generic** view.

Thanks